# Build gridster layout using serialize data (JSON) as input

Tags: jquery, json, gridster

I want to build gridster box layout using JSON as input.

In [http://gridster.net/demos/serialize.html] we get JSON data when we click on serialize. Now how do I build the layout using this JSON as input. Like I want the reverse of serialize, making layout using JSON.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check Demo link

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yoku2010/66xdLzkg/)

I have created a JS plugin to achieve this.

*Calling of the plugin is like this*

```
$('#gridster').makeGridster({
    jsonArr:[],   // Please define your json Array here
    widget_base_dimensions: [100, 55],
    widget_margins: [5, 5]
});
```

From now you have to call makeGrister function instead of gridster. I have added only one property jsonArr other properties are remain same.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks alot Yogesh.:) This is exactly what I wanted. Currently we have 0,1, 2 etc in the boxes. Can we add some text instead of numbers.

Comment: Yes you can. I have change that code according to your requirement . please check that demo again. now you can add "text" property to define text within "li". if you don't define that property, it will remain empty.

Comment: Hey Yogesh, I have one more issue related to gridster. Can you please check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639081/get-text-in-gridster-serialize-data-as-json